# How can I combine 2 or more jquery keydown functions into one function?

Tags: jquery, html

**My goal:**

To clean up multiple keydown functions leading to the same button press by making it one function.

**My issue:**

***I have made many functions like this:***

```
$("#username").keydown(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
        $('#loginbtn').click();
    };
});
$("#password").keydown(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
        $('#loginbtn').click();
    };
});
```

That trigger button clicks on buttons. It is too messy and uses many lines. I want to combine the lines into one function. I have many boxes for my registration form as well.

**What have I tried?**

**1.**
***I have tried the following code bellow and other replications which do not work:***

```
$("#username","#password").keydown(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
        $('#loginbtn').click();
    };
});
```

**2.**
***Another idea I had was to use a class, I just don't know if this is considered the "proper" way to do it, so I need opinions:***

```
$(".logintextbox").keydown(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
        $('#loginbtn').click();
    };
});
```

Then I would also add that class in my html so all of the login text boxes and all of the register text boxes have unique classes "grouping" them.

**My question/tl;dr:**

*How can I combine 2 or more jquery keydown functions into one function using multiple id's or one class?*

Comment: +1, Very well written question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest delegating from your form instead of individual elements.

```
$("#your_form_id").on('keydown', 'input', function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
        $('#loginbtn').click();
    };
});
```

This will capture the key being pressed on all inputs within your form.

Comment: Do I even need the `,'input'` part of this?

Comment: @Pachonk, that will be the ideal choice to only capture the keydown events on only `<input>` elements and not anywhere else.

Comment: So the input is actually narrowing, not broadening?

Comment: Thank you for providing a dead on strait forward answer! Also, how do you think my question quality was? It's been something I've been working on majorly.

Comment: @Pachonk, Very good actually. Detailing your attempts. I understood what you needed in reading few lines.

Answer (score 3):

Selecting multiple elements. `$('#username, #password')`. The second argument to `$` is the context.

Comment: God, I tried looking for this for hours, just had no idea what to Google. Thanks, I have up-voted as this is working, but I will wait for a few more answers to see if anybody possibly has a stronger answer. If everybody answers exactly the same, you will be the best answer. Thanks.

Comment: I apoligize, @Starx 's answer is better, more towards what I was looking for.

Comment: ahah that's fine ;). Remember to keep a cheatsheet of css selectors